# What LED driver should I use

Tags: led

I am wiring up a house where the kitchen has multiple LED strips. All I have is a wire hanging out of the light strips. And as the LED lights are built into the cabinets I cannot get inside them to see any labels on current, voltage etc.
I have multiple LED drivers in the house but are not sure which one goes on which light. 
Is there an easy way to figure this out?

Comment: Can you fit a camera in there?  Or a cheap endoscope?  Do you have any information about the original driver?  Unless it's a custom job it is very likely 12V or 24V drive, but are you sure a driver isn't already embedded?  If so the wires may require line voltage, and the nature of the bit sticking out may provide hits.  You may need to experimentally determine the rating.  If you get a dimmable current driver and a voltmeter, you can slowly increase drive current while you watch the brightness, and when you reach a plausible brightness at a standard voltage measure the current.  A bit risky.

Comment: Thanks, I inherited this job from a person that left the company. He has left multiple 12v and 24v drives laying around the site with no indication as to what lights they go on. No driver is not embedded as very thin wires coming out of light and we have the drivers. Yes we have info about the drivers, its just a matter of matching them up to the correct lights. The lights are strips built into the cabinet and I cannot see any way to get into them without damaging them, even an inspection scope would be hard to get in.

Comment: Thin wires?  How thin, about what gauge?  Are the drivers constant voltage or current?  Any adjustments possible?  What are the current ratings of the drivers? Manufacturer and part number?  What can you see regarding the strips?  PCB or tape?  Color? Length?  Can you see components, e.g. resistors?  How about some pics of the strips, cabinet, wires, and drivers?

Comment: Yeah guage and the exact label on the casing would help.  If you really need to be sure, stick an endoscope in there or try to find the purchase records.  It is very unlikely you will burn the LEDs out if you try the 12V driver first, but yeah, due diligence first. 24v drivers will almost instantly burn out 12V leds.

Answer (score 3):

You said you cant get to the lamp. How will you change the lamps in the future?

You really do need to get in there and find the label with the specifications.

Or you can contact the cabinet maker/installer.

Then size your power supply according to the lamp power requirements.

Comment: It's probably high end custom cabinetry and he's probably trying to figure it out without involving the millworkers.  If they have to return to site and take apart something fancy, even for a short visit it could run $300+damages.  Because of their long life, I've seen LEDs used in quite a number of "semipermanent" installs, especially in areas with fine finish.  @WaynePatt Do make sure you thoroughly check if there's an easy uninstall method for the cabinets.  Some mounting methods are surprisingly easy to pop open once you figure out how they work but still feel rock solid.

Answer (score 0):

More information would help. especially about the drivers. See my comment.

Knowing as little as I know now, I would use a constant current LED driver with a wide supply voltage range and current adjustment from zero to full power.

I would set the current to about 20 mA.

If they emit any light, measure the voltage.  Decrease the current to 10 mA and measure the voltage.  If the voltage is the same, then there are no current limiting resistors.

If they do not emit any light, then incrementally increase the current up to 100 mA. Measure the voltage.

You could also use a voltage supply with current limiting. Set the current limit low and increase then voltage while monitoring the current.

LED strips are powered with voltages that range from 5v up to hundreds of volts. Without knowing more I cannot even guess what test voltage/current ranges to use.

If you had no drivers I'd start with a 24V CC driver like a Mean Well HLG-40-24B, emphasis on type B for a wide range current increments. If no light is emitted than a 36V then a 54V.

Even description of the strips could help, even just length and width.